# Building An Electric Cart

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, battery-operated

I am trying to build some sort of electric cart, to help me push something. The cart would have to push about 120-150 pounds. It wouldn't have to completely push the whole thing, just assist me with pushing it at a slow speed (5-7 mph). My primary objective is to keep costs down. It needs to be battery powered. There's not much else I can think to clarify, so I will say any extra information if requested.

I have done a little bit of research, but I am new in this field, and help would be nice. I was thinking about using [this motor](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-aerodrive-sk3-5055-280kv-brushless-outrunner-motor.html), but as I said, I don't know too much. Maybe a [battery like this](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-5000mah-6s-40c-lipo-pack-xt90.html)? I also don't really know what speed controller would be nice.

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: For running at constant speed you only need the rolling friction and the drive train losses. You also need to specify the maximum acceleration required and on what gradient. It will all be much simpler if you switch to metric units.

Comment: Exactly what do you by 'push about 120-150 pounds'? Is that the force the cart has to push the 'something' with?

Comment: One of the big factors is rolling resistance, and that varies enormously on different surfaces. Ditto gradient. Add usage information (indoors, outdoors, smooth floors, pavement, sand and rocks, climbing hills or wheelchair ramps)  to the question. Plus, how long you want it to run.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will be using this outdoors on sidewalk, but there really won't be any gradient. I would like it to run at least 30 minutes, but as I said, I don't really know how much that is to ask of a battery. The 120-150 pounds is the weight of the thing I am pushing, so I would assume that means the cart has to push 120-150 pounds, but I am not sure. I think that's all, but tell me if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the coefficient of friction between the cart's wheels and the underlying floor.

From that, and how much "pushing" assistance you want, you have defined the **MINUMUM** weight of the cart.